# Cannot maintain persistent XMPP connection from sticky service android

Tags: android, xmpp, android-service, smack, asmack

**Environment**: For uninterrupted delivery of messages from one-to-one/one-to-many devices, I have XMPPService running in the background as STICKY service.
To receive messages, I have PacketListener which fires whenever a packet arrives at the device. I am using asmack library for client side implementation and OpenFire as my XMPP server.

```
public class XMPPService extends Service implements INetworkReceiver {
private XMPPConnection mXmppConnection;
private XMPPMethods xmpp;
private DatabaseHandler db;
private UserDetails user;
private SmackAndroid smack;
private Registrations registrations;
private static final String TAG="XMPPService";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
    return new LocalBinder<XMPPService>(this);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registrations=new Registrations(getApplicationContext());
    xmpp=XMPPMethodsImpl.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    db=DatabaseHandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    if(db!=null){
        user=db.getUserDetails();
    }
    createConnection();     
}

public void createConnection()
{
    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
            AppConstants.HOST, AppConstants.PORT);
    connConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
    connConfig.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    connConfig.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
    connConfig.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
    mXmppConnection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);


    Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        private Handler handler=new Handler();
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                if(mXmppConnection!=null && !mXmppConnection.isConnected()){
                    mXmppConnection.connect();
                    Log.i("XMPPServiceAsync",
                            "Connected to " + mXmppConnection.getHost());
                    xmpp.setConnection(mXmppConnection);
                }
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //mXmppConnection.addConnectionListener(new XmppConnectionListener());

            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if(db!=null && user!=null && mXmppConnection!=null && !mXmppConnection.isAuthenticated()){
                            if(user.getUserName()!=null && !user.getUserName().isEmpty()){
                                mXmppConnection.login(user.getUserName(), "Tp@!");
                                xmpp.setPresence(2, mXmppConnection);
                                xmpp.setConnection(mXmppConnection);
                                Log.i("XMPPServiceAsync",
                                        "Logged in as " + mXmppConnection.getUser());

                            }
                        }
                    }catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    if(mXmppConnection.isConnected()){
                        xmpp.rejoinGroups();
                        registrations.registerMessageListener(mXmppConnection);
                        registrations.registerPacketListener(mXmppConnection);
                        registrations.registerMultiUserInvitationListener(mXmppConnection, db, user);
                        registrations.registerPingListener(mXmppConnection);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });

    if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW )
    { 
        Log.i(TAG,"Thread State: "+ thread.getState()+"");
        thread.start(); 
    } 
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags,
        final int startId) {
    //rejoining rooms
    try{
        Log.v("XMPP Connection before rejoining",mXmppConnection+"");
        if(mXmppConnection.isConnected()){
            registrations.registerMessageListener(mXmppConnection);
            registrations.registerPacketListener(mXmppConnection);
            registrations.registerMultiUserInvitationListener(mXmppConnection, db, user);
            registrations.registerPingListener(mXmppConnection);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public boolean onUnbind(final Intent intent) {
    return super.onUnbind(intent);

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public void reEstablishConnection() {
    createConnection();
}
```

}

**Problem:** When device remains idle for some time, device disconnects from the XMPP server and connection goes null which is against the specifications of XMPP protocol which states that XMPP server maintains persistent connection with devices until we logout forcefully. Reason behind connection going null is not known. When connection goes null, PacketListener stops working.

**What all I have tried:**

1. Implemented sticky service for connecting to server and initializing listeners.
2. Implemented AlarmManager to check if the service is running in the background. It also checks if the connection is alive and authenticated periodically. (Drains Battery)
3. Implemented Ping manager according to XMPP specification XEP-0199.

**Can someone please look into this.**

Comment: are you able to resolve the issue,am having the same issue

Comment: not yet. can you explain exactly what are you experiencing?

Comment: Same issue i have registered packet listener in service not listening after few mins

Comment: I am still looking for the solution. Will share it once i resolve the problem.

Comment: okay,any idea how to make it persistent i can try same

Answer (score 1):

> When device remains idle for some time, device disconnects from the XMPP server and connection goes null

Most likely, your process was terminated. [This is perfectly normal](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle).

> which is against the specifications of XMPP protocol which states that XMPP server maintains persistent connection with devices until we logout forcefully.

Then no mobile device can comply with the XMPP protocol specifications, as Internet access is not guaranteed and universal. Also, users can get rid of your process whenever the user wants to.

> Implemented sticky service for connecting to server and initializing listeners.

This will cause your process, and your service, to be restarted sometime after Android terminates the process. During the window of time between your process being terminated and your process being restarted, you will not be in communication with the XMPP server.

Comment: Then how are applications like WhatsApp and Telegram able to maintain persistent connection with their server and keep on listening for any new packet that arrives on the device. I am clueless how to implement such thing. Initializing connection in service and adding listeners to the connection is the only thing i could think of.

Comment: @subhendupsingh: I do not use those apps. They could be using Google Cloud Messaging. They could be using a foreground service.

Comment: GCM is not the solution for a real time chat application.I understand that my process is getting terminated but when it restarts, connection and listeners should start working again but they don't until i start my application again. How can i keep my connection and listeners alive in the background. I don't want to use foreground service.

Comment: @subhendupsingh: "connection and listeners should start working again but they don't until i start my application again" -- then you need to figure out what in your code is running when Android restarts your sticky service, and move your connection code there. "How can i keep my connection and listeners alive in the background. I don't want to use foreground service" -- if you are not going to use a foreground service, and you are not going to use GCM, then you will simply have to live with your sticky service.

Answer (score 0):

What commonsware said. START_STICKY just means that Android is free to kill your service when it needs the resources otherwise. It will restart your service after some time. But you are responsible to reestablish the XMPP connection when it happens.

Comment: As you can see in the code I posted, I have written code for establishing connection and initializing listeners in onCreate of the service. Further to test, I have also written code to initialize listeners in onStartCommand of the service. None of them works when the device remains idle for sometime. I know what START_STICKY does but even if the service is restarted then according to the logic, connection should be reestablished. I just want to know is this the correct way to establish persistent connection and have listeners working all the time or do i need to take some other approach.

Comment: Then I'd guess your `createConnection()` does not work. I see not obvious flaw after a quick look at it, but it looks circuitous to have a thread and a handler for this.

Comment: If there would have been a problem in createConnection() then it would not work even for the first time i.e when the app is started, but it does. Can we use GCM in conjunction with xmpp because that would not require a background service at all. If not, is there a way to send intent from server to device so that broadcast receiver fires itself whenever a packet with specified intent arrives.